# Complex Integral over a rectangular contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let C be a rectangle with corners $\pm 2\pm 3i$ in the anticlockwise direction. Find $$\int_c\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}dz$$

I tried:

Split the contour in to 4 parts: $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$.

Let's say $C_1$ is the the bottom side of the rectangle. So,

$C_1: f(t) =t-3i, -2\le t\le 2$

Then I find $$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1}{t-3i}+\frac{1}{t-3i-1}dt$$

Similarly, I would find the integrals over $C_2, C_3$ and $C_4$. Then, the final answer is the sum of $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It's much simpler to use the Residue Theorem.

Comment: Your first integral has a lower limit of $c$ and no upper limit

Comment: @mrnovice that is standard notation...

Comment: Oh ok, this is a topic beyond me then

Comment: The two poles are inside the contour, just use the residue theorem.

Comment: Or Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: Anyways, to the actual question, yes, you can and probably should do what you are doing.

Comment: It will be so painful to consider the integral as is because you have to consider the branch of logarithms.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. I haven't learned the Residue Theorem, yet, so I can't use that. But how do I use the Cauchy Integral Theorem if f(z) is not analytic at z = 0 and z = 1 and 0, 1 are both inside C? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that the OP is receptive to seeing how Cauchy's Integral Formula can be used to evaluate the integral of interest.

Let $C$ be a closed rectifiable contour with winding number $1$ about a point $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$.  Cauchy's Integral Formula states that if $f$ is analytic on the open region enclosed by $C$ and continuous on $C, then

$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz \tag 1$$

---

In $(1)$, set $f(z)=1$, $z_0=0$ and $C$ to be the rectangle defined in the OP.  Then from $(1)$ we have

$$1=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{z}\,dz$$

whereupon solving for $\oint_C \frac{1}{z}\,dz$ reveals

$$\oint_C \frac{1}{z}\,dz=2\pi i \tag 2$$

---

Similarly, set $f(z)=1$ and $z_0=1$.  Then from $(1)$ we have

$$1=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{z-1}\,dz$$

whereupon solving for $\oint_C \frac{1}{z}\,dz$ reveals

$$\oint_C \frac{1}{z-1}\,dz=2\pi i  \tag3$$

---

Putting together $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields

$$\oint_C \left(\frac1z+\frac1{z-1}\right)\,dz=4\pi i$$

Comment: The integral I'm looking for is $$\int_c\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}dz$$, so shouldn't the correct answer be $4\pi i$? Also, do the corners of the rectangle not matter at all when using the cauchy integral formula?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  It's $4\pi i$.  The corners don't matter.  The contour need only be rectilinear.

Comment: @sucksatmath Since you're new to the site, I wanted to you know that after you  have enough reputation points you can up vote answers too.  -Mark

Comment: I thought the OP was asking to demonstrate that the Cauchy's integral formula yields the correct result with a specific calculation of the four legs of the contour integral for a rectangular curve.

Comment: @bkocsis Read the premable of the answer and then read the referenced comments.

Comment: @bkocsis Did you down vote this answer?  If so, do you see that the OP accepted it?  That implies that your conjecture was flawed.